# Having Trouble Parsing JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

So I've created a service call, and as of now it is working. This is the link to the URL which you must see to be able to help me:

http://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=python&location=new+york

For some reason, my code here isn't able to retrieve the dictionary objects of the data. It returns SIGABRT.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *urlString = @"http://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=python&location=new+york";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;

    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray *jobs = json[@" "];

    for (NSDictionary *theJob in jobs)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", theJob[@"description"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the SIGABRT? at which line?

Comment: Side note: don't do this on the main thread.  Use GCD's `dispatch_async`, NSOperationQueue, or the asynchronous methods of NSURLConnection.

Comment: Those methods are huge and kind of bulky. I'm still a beginner to Web Services, so I need to cover the basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is an array of dictionaries. Change

```
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray *jobs = json[@" "];
```

to

```
NSArray *jobs = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Comment: I leave it blank because I'm unsure as to what to put in there

Comment: Ah, it seems I have to wait 3 minutes before I can accept your answer